# String change and enumerate values PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, string

i have a string, and I want to change the values to be in rearranged, for example i have this:

```
{
"code_2":"CODGD",
"description_2":"First product",
"price_2":"45.0",
"quantity_2":"1",
"quantityant_2":"1",
"subtotal_2":"45.0",
"code_3":"CODRT",
"description_3":"Second product",
"price_3":"12.68",
"quantity_3":"1",
"quantityant_3":"1",
"subtotal_3":"12.68",
"code_7":"CODPO",
"description_7":"Third product",
"price_7":"434.0",
"quantity_7":"1",
"quantityant_7":"1",
"subtotal_7":"434.0"
}
```

It goes like 2,3 and 7 but i need them to be 1,2,3
Every object are in group of 6; code_1, description_1, price_1, quantity_1, quantityant_1, subtotal_1. 
What I need is that the objects surronded by _ and " be renumerated, for example like this:

```
{
"code_1":"CODGD",
"description_1":"First product",
"price_1":"45.0",
"quantity_1":"1",
"quantityant_1":"1",
"subtotal_1":"45.0",
"code_2":"CODRT",
"description_2":"Second product",
"price_2":"12.68",
"quantity_2":"1",
"quantityant_2":"1",
"subtotal_2":"12.68",
"code_3":"CODPO",
"description_3":"Third product",
"price_3":"434.0",
"quantity_3":"1",
"quantityant_3":"1",
"subtotal_3":"434.0"
}
```

I been thinking in using str_replace but im a little lost.

Hope you can help me.

Thanks

Extra details
I actually get the info in an array with this form:

```
 Array([code_2] => CODGD[description_2] => First product[price_2] => 45.0[quantity_2] => 1[quantityant_2] => 1[subtotal_2] => 45.0[code_3] => CODRT[description_3] => Second product[price_3] => 45.0[quantity_3] => 1[quantityant_3] => 1[subtotal_3] => 45.0[code_7] => CODPO[description_7] => Third product[price_7] => 23.43[quantity_7] => 1[quantityant_7] => 1[subtotal_7] => 23.43)
```

Comment: share your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it like below:-

```
<?php
$string = '{"code_2":"CODGD", "description_2":"First product", "price_2":"45.0", "quantity_2":"1", "quantityant_2":"1", "subtotal_2":"45.0", "code_3":"CODRT", "description_3":"Second product", "price_3":"12.68", "quantity_3":"1", "quantityant_3":"1", "subtotal_3":"12.68", "code_7":"CODPO", "description_7":"Third product", "price_7":"434.0", "quantity_7":"1", "quantityant_7":"1", "subtotal_7":"434.0"}';

echo "<pre/>";print_r($array = json_decode($string,true));

$final_array = array();
$i = 1;
for($j = 0;$j<3;$j++){
foreach ($array as $key=>$val){

   $final_array[explode('_',$key)[0].'_'.$i] = $val;
 }
  $i++;
}

echo "<pre/>";print_r($final_array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/725237

***A much better solution (After looking my first attempt itself):-***

```
<?php
$string = '{"code_2":"CODGD", "description_2":"First product", "price_2":"45.0", "quantity_2":"1", "quantityant_2":"1", "subtotal_2":"45.0", "code_3":"CODRT", "description_3":"Second product", "price_3":"12.68", "quantity_3":"1", "quantityant_3":"1", "subtotal_3":"12.68", "code_7":"CODPO", "description_7":"Third product", "price_7":"434.0", "quantity_7":"1", "quantityant_7":"1", "subtotal_7":"434.0"}';

echo "<pre/>";print_r($array = json_decode($string,true));
$final_array = array();
$i = 1;
$j = 1;
foreach ($array as $key=>$val){
   if($j ==7){
     $i +=1;
     $j = 1;
   }
   $final_array[explode('_',$key)[0].'_'.$i] = $val;
   $j++;
}

echo "<pre/>";print_r($final_array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/725252

Comment: Hi Anant, this works, but the values are generated randomly, sometimes they are 2,3,7 other times can be 1,4,8, they are not always the same

Comment: @user2312198  check my current answer

Comment: This way works great, thanks a lot anant for helping me

Comment: @user2312198  because you have 6 indexes which are repeated into the array with change in number

Answer (score 1):

Your string is JSON formatted, so it can be decoded and processed without cumbersome `str_replace` juggling.

```
$json = <<<JSON
{"code_2":"CODGD", "description_2":"First product", "price_2":"45.0", "quantity_2":"1", "quantityant_2":"1", "subtotal_2":"45.0", "code_3":"CODRT", "description_3":"Second product", "price_3":"12.68", "quantity_3":"1", "quantityant_3":"1", "subtotal_3":"12.68", "code_7":"CODPO", "description_7":"Third product", "price_7":"434.0", "quantity_7":"1", "quantityant_7":"1", "subtotal_7":"434.0"}
JSON;

$data = json_decode($json, true);
$items = array_chunk($data, 6, true);
$items = array_combine(range(1, count($items)), $items);
$out = array();
foreach ($items as $idx => $item) {
    foreach ($item as $k => $v) {
        $k = preg_replace('/^(.+)_\d+$/', '$1_' . $idx, $k);
        $out[$k] = $v;
    }
}
$json = json_encode($out);
echo $json;
```